# How can I store a per-process variable, similar to how unix stores the pwd per-process?

Tags: c, bash, unix, tags, filesystems

I'm trying to write a command line utility with an API analogous to the filesystem API (cd, pwd, ls, etc).

The utility I'm trying to write operates on sets of tags instead of folders. Instead of being in folder x/y/z, you're at the intersection of sets x+y+z.

I was going to store the equivalent of the working directory in an environment variable so each shell could have it's own working set of tags, but have run into a snag. When a child process is spawned to change the working set, it gets it's own copy of all environment variables, then, when it exits, the parent processes environment variables are left untouched.

Can anyone think of another way to approach this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: If you look a little closer, you will see that some commands (most notably `cd`) doesn't actually exist as a command in `/bin` or `/usr/bin` or any other place on disk. This is because it *can't* exist as a free-standing command, since it changes the working directory of the current process only. Those commands a built into the shell (like Bash) and handled internally in the shell program. And it seems to me that what you want is to make your own shell-like program.

Comment: Child processes cannot manipulate the parent's environment. You'll have to re-think your design.

Comment: I asked about this on irc, and got a clever answer. Bash functions aren't run in a child process, so I could wrap my program in a shell function that takes care of updating the environment variable.

It brings along a few complications, like having to provide wrappers for each shell, but is a path forwards.

Answer (score 0):

I asked the same question on irc and got a satisfying answer.

Bash functions aren't run as child processes, so I can wrap my executable in a shell function and let the function update the environment variable.